# Где найти Российские Proxy?

Tags: ip, proxy, vpn, прокси

Есть необходимость в прокси, IP адреса которых были бы распределены по всем регионам РФ(ну или почти). В идеале - по одному адресу на регион. К сожалению не смог найти сервисов, которые бы предоставляли такую услугу. Собственно вопрос: где найти?) Может быть существуют зарубежные сайты, которые имеют IP в РФ?

Comment: Платные или бесплатные?

Comment: Можно в принципе платные

Comment: Купи симок с разных регионов)

Answer (score 1):

Использовал прокси от https://awmproxy.com/
приемлемая цена, скорость и есть фильтр по странам. Также есть бесплатные прокси, но они медленные и могут некоторые не работать. С разбивкой по городам России еще не встречал.